# Website to excel data fetching

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone please help in fetching data from website to excel using VBA, i need property address in excel cell:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

ie.navigate "xyz.org"
ie.Visible = True
Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = ie.document
    ie.document.all("input-search-field").Value = Range("b1").Value
Dim obj     As Object
    For Each obj In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")
        If obj.className = "btn btn-default search-button" Then
            obj.Click
            Exit For
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim isPropertyAddr  As Boolean
    isPropertyAddr = ie.document.getElementById("LoanObject").ie.document.getelementbytagname("SPAN")
    isPropertyAddr = True
    Debug.Print ie.document.getattributes("classname"), ie.document.getattributes("tagname")

    MsgBox obj.innerText
```

[dom code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUfW6.png)

Comment: I have added in pictures

Comment: Great! I see it now. I would loop all `span` elements looking for one that has the innertext of "Property Address" then set a flag so on the next iteration (next span) I can grab the next span's innertext.

Comment: I tried it but didnt work for me can you tell me the exact code that you could use here?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
IsAddressFound = False
For Each obj In ie.document.getElementById("LoanObject").getElementsByTagname("SPAN")
    If InStr(obj.Innertext, "Property Address") > 0 Then
        IsAddressFound = True
    End If
    If IsAddressFound Then
        Debug.Print obj.Innertext 'Your address populates here
        IsAddressFound = False
    End If
Next
```

Thanks